# Kendo dateTimePickerFor sending NULL or 01/01/0001 00:00 to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetimepicker, kendo-asp.net-mvc

The view is working correctly and I can see the datetimepicker but when I click submit the datetime fields are null (if nullable) or 01/01/0001 00:00 if not nullable.

View

```html
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LaycanStartDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-12" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LaycanStartDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LaycanStartDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
 </div>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
                var date = moment(value, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm", true).format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm");
                return this.optional(element) || moment(date, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm", true).isValid();
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Model

```
[Display(Name = "LaycanStartDate", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))]
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}")]
        public DateTime LaycanStartDate { get; set; }
```

DateTime.cshtml

```
@model DateTime? 
@(Html.Kendo().DateTimePickerFor(m => m).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%; max-width: 280px", title = "datetimepicker"}))
```

Comment: This means that binding failed, not that the control sent NULL or a zero date. It could be that instead of an ISO8601  date, a localized string was posted with a format that doesn't match the server's.You can use Fiddler to check what's actually posted to the server

Comment: A date's display format doesn't have to be the same as the format of the string posted to the server. You can configure the input box to use `dd/MM/YYYY` and still post `YYYY-MM-dd` to the server

Comment: Thanks. So Fiddler shows the values are coming through correctly but after binding in the ActionResult it's wrong. How can I change the format back to ISO on post?

Comment: Correcly means they are in ISO8601 form, ie `2019-03-28`. Otherwise they are strings that need parsing which can fail

Comment: Cool. So how do I get the view to re-parse them into ISO?

Comment: Do I have to add string fields to the model and map to that and then convert in the controller? Seems like overkill

Comment: How do you format the date picker? What you posted simply creates the input, it doesn't configure its properties. That's where you should set formatting.

Comment: @model DateTime?

@(Html.Kendo().DateTimePickerFor(m => m).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%; max-width: 280px", title = "datetimepicker"}))

Comment: Post that in the question please. This is the most important code. You can set the `Format` , culture and binding information there. [Check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43545459/how-can-i-get-the-kendo-ui-mvc-datetimepicker-to-format-the-date-unambiguously-i?rq=1) for example.

Comment: BTW in my own code I've never set the format on the model and simply use `@(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(x => x.Start).Name("start"))`. When needed, I add `Format()`.

Comment: Thanks. Getting there. I can't set the Name("") because it needs to inherit from the EditorFor in the view. I've tried Format("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm") as well as .Culture("en-GB") and .ParseFormats(new String[] { "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm" }) and .ParseFormats(new String[] { "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm" })... no luck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190827/discussion-between-evan-barke-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Answer (score 0):

So the only way I was eventually able to get around this was to remove the binding on the controller [Bind(....

Without that it allows the value through and the controller can deal with the format